# Use the mongoDb and MySQL together

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongoose, audit, audit-trail

I have a application where I need to maintain the audit log operation performed on the collection. I am currently using the MongoDB for storage purpose which work well so far. 
Now for audit log I am thinking to use the MySQL database where reasons are-

**1.** Using the mongo implicit audit filter degrade the performance.

**2.** Storage will be huge if I store the logs also in the mongoDB which will impact in replication of nodes in cluster.

Conditions to see the logs are not very often in application, so thinking to store logs out of main storage. I am confused to use mongoDB with MySQL, also is this a right choice for future perspective.

Also Is MySQL a good choice to store the audit log, or any other database can help me in storage and conditional query later.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is not guaranteed to go to a completely different database system only for this purpose.

My first attempt for separation would be creating a new database in your current database system and forward to there or even using a normal text file.

Give your feedbacks.